# How to populate the highest parent node/ Root node next to a child node in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros, treeview, parent-child

I am new to excel macros and VBA and have been struggling with the following issue. I have the following Dataset in Excel:

```
Parent Child

AAA   BBB
AAA   CCC
AAA   DDD
BBB   EEE
BBB   FFF
CCC   GGG
FFF   HHH
III   JJJ
JJJ   KKK
JJJ   LLL
```

I wish to populate the child nodes with their respective highest level roots nodes such that all child nodes have a root level data/parent mapped to them something like this:

```
Node    1st Level Node
AAA     Root
BBB     AAA
CCC     AAA
DDD     AAA
EEE     AAA
FFF     AAA
GGG     AAA
HHH     AAA
III     Root
JJJ     III
KKK     III
LLL     III
```

I have tried creating a VB function to create a tree but am unable to take it from there to populate the last or highest level root to the respective child nodes.

I also tried using logic such as finding unique child names and backtracking to find the master root but unable to do so.

VB Code:

```
Sub MakeTree()

    Dim r As Integer

    For r = 1 To Range("Data").Rows.Count
        If Range("Data").Cells(r, 1) = "Root" Then
            DrawNode Range("Data").Cells(r, 2), 0, 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub DrawNode(ByRef header As String, ByRef row As Integer, ByRef depth As Integer)

    Cells(Range("Destination").row + row, Range("Destination").Column + depth) = header

    Dim r As Integer

    For r = 1 To Range("Data").Rows.Count
        If Range("Data").Cells(r, 1) = header Then

            row = row + 1
            DrawNode Range("Data").Cells(r, 2), row, depth + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

How can I go ahead and do the same.

Comment: assuming that its a sorted list, I would use a dictionary. Using Child nodes as the key and parent nodes as the value. Every iteration check if the parent value exists in the child dictionary as a key and if yes then replace the value with that.

Comment: I think the result data that you had put in your question does not explain it properly. Like `KKK` root is `JJJ` but it is showing `III` , similarly `BBB` should be `Root` not `AAA`. Can you give a proper example

Comment: Hi. I have removed the AAA and III parent roots. But KKK root is III not JJJ. It needs to traverse to the highest level Node. A node which has no parent or Parent as "Root" is the highest level.

Answer (score 0):

assuming parent is in column A and child in column B, the following macro will put the result in column D and E

```
Option Explicit
Sub Root_Parent()
    Dim i, re, k
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Set re = Range("B:B").Find(Cells(i, 1))
        If re Is Nothing Then
            Set re = Range("D:D").Find(Cells(i, 1))
            If re Is Nothing Then
                k = k + 1
                Cells(k, 4) = Cells(i, 1)
                Cells(k, 5) = "Root"
                findchild Cells(k, 4).Value, k
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
Sub findchild(parent, ByRef k)
 Dim i, s, re
 i = 2
    While Cells(i, 2) <> ""
    s = i
        Do
            Set re = Range("B:B").Find(Cells(s, 1))
            If re Is Nothing Then
                If Cells(s, 1) = parent Then
                k = k + 1
                Cells(k, 4) = Cells(i, 2)
                Cells(k, 5) = Cells(s, 1)
                End If
                Exit Do
            Else
                s = re.Row
            End If
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```